# Why removing rows with NA values from the majority class improves model performance

Tags: python, pandas, class-imbalance, missing-data, smote

I have an imbalanced dataset like so:

```py
df['y'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
```

```
No     92.769441
Yes     7.230559
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

The dataset consists of 13194 rows and 37 features.

I have tried numerous attempts to improve the performance of my models by oversampling and undersampling to balance the data, One Class SVM for outlier detection, using different scores, hyperparametre tuning, etc. Some of these methods have improved the performance slightly, but not as much as I would like:

Applying RandomUnderSampling:

```py
from imblearn.under_sampling import RandomUnderSampler
rus = RandomUnderSampler(random_state=42)
X_train_rus, y_train_rus = rus.fit_resample(X_train, y_train)

# Define and fit AdaBoost classifier using undersampled data 
ada_rus = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
ada_rus.fit(X_train_rus,y_train_rus)
y_pred_rus = ada_rus.predict(X_test) 

evaluate_model(y_test, y_pred_rus)
```

[image]

Using Oversampling techniques such as SMOTE:

```py
# SMOTE
from imblearn.over_sampling import SMOTE

# upsample minority class using SMOTE
sm = SMOTE(random_state=42)
X_train_sm, y_train_sm = sm.fit_sample(X_train, y_train)

# Define and fit AdaBoost classifier using upsample data 
ada_sm = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=100, random_state=42)
ada_sm.fit(X_train_sm,y_train_sm)
y_pred_sm = ada_sm.predict(X_test) 

# compare predicted outcome through AdaBoost upsampled data with real outcome
evaluate_model(y_test, y_pred_sm)
```

[image]

I then decided to attempt removing rows with missing data from samples from the majority class as I saw this in an article. I did this gradually by increasing the threshold (thresh) parameter in pandas dropna function, and each time I removed more rows, the performance improved. Finally, I removed all rows from the majority class with missing data like so:

```py
df_majority_droppedRows = df.query("y == 'No'").dropna()
df_minority = df.query("y == 'Yes'")
dfWithDroppedRows = pd.concat([df_majority_droppedRows, df_minority])
print(dfWithDroppedRows.shape)
```

```py
(1632, 37)
```

This reduced the number of rows I have dramatically down to 1632 and changed the distribution in the target variable such that what was perviously the minority class('Yes') was now the majority class:

```
Yes    58.455882
No     41.544118
Name: y, dtype: float64
```

Testing the model, I found it performed best, with high recall and precision values.

[image]

So my questions are,

1. Why did this method outperform other oversampling and undersampling techniques?
2. Is it acceptable that what was previously a minority class is now the majority class or can this cause overfitting?
3. Is it realistic to build a model that relies on input with no missing data for the majority class samples?

**EDIT**

In response to the questions in the comment by @Ben Reiniger:

- I dealt with the missing values like in the data by using KNNImputer for numeric data and SimpleImputer for categorical data like so:

```py
def preprocess (X):
    # define categorical and numeric transformers
    numeric_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('knnImputer', KNNImputer(n_neighbors=2, weights="uniform")),
        ('scaler', StandardScaler())])

    categorical_transformer = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy='constant', fill_value='missing')),
        ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'))])

    preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, selector(dtype_include=['object'])),
        ('num', numeric_transformer, selector(dtype_include=['float64','int64']))
    ])

    X = pd.DataFrame(preprocessor.fit_transform(X))
    return X
```

- After dropping rows, I defined the feature of matrix and the target, preprocessed and then split the data, like so:

```py
# make feature matrix and target matrix
X = dfWithDroppedRows.drop(columns=['y'])
y = dfWithDroppedRows['y']

# encode target variable 
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
le = LabelEncoder()
y = le.fit_transform(y)

# preprocess feature matrix
X=preprocess(X)

# Split data into training and testing data
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

- Finally, to calculate if the missing values are identically distributed (originally) in the two classes, I ran the following

```py
np.count_nonzero(df.query("y == 'No'").isna()) / df.query("y == 'No'").size
```

```
0.2791467938526762
```

```py
np.count_nonzero(df.query("y == 'Yes'").isna()) / df.query("y == 'Yes'").size
```

```
0.24488639582979205
```

So the majority class has about 28% missing data and the minority class has about 25% missing data.

Comment: How did you deal with the missing values originally?  Did you remake the split after dropping rows?  Are the missing values identically distributed (originally) in the two classes?

Comment: @BenReiniger I have responded to your questions in an edit to the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a combination of two problems in your data:

- imbalance
- missing values

In your experiments there's a confusion about what the true distribution of the data is (or should be): either the "real data" is 97% no, or the "real data" is after removing missing values in which case it's almost balanced. It's very important to decide this based on the problem that you're trying to solve: "in production", does the model have to produce a prediction for every instance even if it has missing values? If yes the true distribution is 97% no (original problem). If no, then the model only predicts for "complete" instances, i.e. many instances are discarded due to missing values (and this happens much more often with "no").

This is a crucial point because whichever way you train the model, it should be evaluated on a test set which reflects the true distribution of the data.

I would assume that your real goal is to predict for every instance, i.e. you don't want to ignore instances even if they have missing values. I will try to address both options though:

- option A: real data is 97% no.
- option B: real data is 58% yes.

> 1. Why did this method outperform other oversampling and undersampling techniques?

The two methods were evaluated on two very different test sets, so the performance between them is simply not comparable.

- If the resampling experiments were [properly evaluated on the original data](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/15630/64377) (*not* resampled), then they provide you with a reliable estimate of the performance in option A.
- If the resampling experiments were (wrongly) evaluated on resampled data, then the difference is certainly due to the missing values, because imputing a very large proportion of the data causes a lot of noise. In this case the resampling experiments are neither valid for option A (wrong distribution in the test set) nor B (missing values in the test set).

> 2. Is it acceptable that what was previously a minority class is now the majority class or can this cause overfitting?

It depends which problem you're trying to solve:

- For the original problem "option A", no it is not acceptable to modify the distribution in the test set.
- For the new problem "option B", the majority class is "yes". The original data with 97% "no" is irrelevant.

> 3. Is it realistic to build a model that relies on input with no missing data for the majority class samples?

This is about specifying the exact problem you want to solve, that's for you to decide :)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer @Erwan. Just to be clear, in the case of resampling, the test set was not resampled. I agree with what you are saying about defining the objective of the model, thanks.

Comment: However, I still feel I do not have an answer to my main question, which is "why did removing rows with NA values from the majority class improve the model performance"? Could it be that the imputation methods I used were not ideal, so samples with imputed data were unreliable and were affecting my model performance negatively?

Comment: @sums22 it's a mistake to interpret these results as an improvement of performance, because the two are not evaluated on the same task: the first task with strong imbalance and lots of missing values is much harder than the second one, that's the main reason why the performance differs. If you want to know the exact reasons which explain why the first problem is "harder", you could run 2 additional experiments: one with missing values but balanced data, one with imbalance but no missing values. This way you could see how much each factor contributes to the difference.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But isn't part of ML to manipulate your dataset by imputing, resampling, feature selection, dropping rows, etc. to get a model with better performance? Don't we change the dataset and get a different "task" with every one of these steps?

Comment: So isn't my method to remove all rows from majority class with missing data similar to RandomUnderSampling? Didn't both methods lead to a more balanced dataset by removing samples? Or is the problem that I didn't then test the model with real data with the original data distribution (97% no)?

Comment: Sorry ignore the comment before last, I think I understand now! So the problem with my method is that I didn't evaluate it on "real" data. Unless, as you said, I expect to receive data with no missing values, and majority class "yes", my results are unreliable. So I think the next step would be to evaluate it on real data, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly: the big difference is indeed whether changes are made only in the training set or the test set. the changes made in the training set are part of the method we use in order to reach the goal, whereas modifying the test set means changing the goal itself. I suspect that a big part of the problem is indeed the imputing, it's a valid method but personally I try to avoid it because we can't really know if the resulting data "makes sense", it's basically generating artificial data.

Comment: Thank you so much, you've really helped. I know what you mean about imputing, especially as I am dealing with medical data, imputing is a difficult choice and maybe not the best one. What do you tend to do then in the case of large amounts of missing data? (I know it is a frowned upon to ask further questions in the comment section, but I would love to hear your opinion!)

Comment: It's a complex issue: expert knowledge is important to understand what the missing values "mean" (if anything) and decide what to do. In general it's important to distinguish missing at random vs not at random, there have been a [few](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/38138) [questions](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/77434) [about](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/88242) this. There are cases where the instances can be removed, or even the feature. Otherwise an option I tend to use is to represent the fact that the value is missing with either a special value if the ...

Comment: ... feature is categorical or an additional boolean feature if not (like in my answer in the last link). But I'm not particularly expert on this, there might be more solid approaches I'm not aware of.

Comment: Thank you for answering all my questions, I really do appreciate it! :)

Comment: Last question! When you suggested I run 2 additional experiments: one with missing values but balanced data, one with imbalance but no missing values; do you mean to run these by altering the whole set (both train and test) to see the effects it will have on the results and therefore understand which problem (missing values or class imbalance) is contributing more to the poor model performance?

Comment: @sums22 yes, that's what I meant: you would need to train and evaluate on a dataset which has the required property (either balanced with missing values or imbalanced without missing values). These experiments would have no other goal than understanding what happens, of course. You could use a subset of data for example, since the effect would probably be similar even if the performance is not optimal.

Comment: makes sense, thank you.